# Steam offline not working but prompt looping

Tags: steam

Basically it gives me this prompt when I hit the Offline Mode button, and it keeps repeating. Even after I restart there's still no luck. Can anyone help?

[image: screenshot of the Steam prompt]

Comment: Are you somewhere that blocks Steam?

Comment: Have you successfully logged in before trying to go offline?  IIRC, you need to log in at least once so that Steam can validate your account, before going offline.  (If you haven't checked the "remember my password" checkbox, try that while logging in, too)

Comment: More generally, please update the question with a list of things you have already tried, and failed with, so that we don't waste time suggesting things you've already done.

Comment: @Steve-O Yes, you do have to login online and switch to offline mode, seemingly to get a token that works offline.